# Google sheets , When Checkbox checked change currency

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox

I can't figure out how to change the currency in my sheets when I press the Checkbox.
[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vN14WheuYLkXSQraI7npLFBywy1XsSHP8SmG7E_0c1A/edit?usp=sharing)

I want :

1. When pressed(checkbox on LINE : **B10**)
2. Columns : from: C10 to L10 changes to Eu(€)

I know that I can Format to any currency manually, but I'm doing this for an old person, so I'm trying to make this as convenient and easy as possible.

Comment: is there a formula that populates the C10:L10 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the help of **Google Apps Script** and **Installable Triggers**.

**How to open Google Apps Script in Google Sheets?**

In your Spreadsheet, Go to **Tools** -> **Script Editor**.

**How to create Installable Trigger?**

> - Open your Apps Script project.
> - At the left, click Triggers alarm.
> - At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
> - Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create. For this case, Click the drop down menu below **Select event type** and select **On Edit**
> - Click Save.

Your trigger should look like this:

[image: triggers]

### Example:

**Code:**

```
function convertToEU(e) {
  var range = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  //check if the row is greater than or equal to 10 and
  //check if the edited column is B
  if(row >= 10 && range.match(/^B[\d]+$/)){
    var sh = e.range.getSheet();
    //change format to EU if checked
    if(e.range.isChecked()){
      sh.getRange("C"+row+":K"+row).setNumberFormat("€ #,##00.00")
    }else{
      //change to KR if unchecked
      sh.getRange("C"+row+":K"+row).setNumberFormat("#,##00.00 kr")
    }
  }
}
```

**Unchecked:**

[image: unchecked]

**Checked:**

[image: checked]

References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. It worked perfectly